# Distinguish between URL username and Basic auth username?

Tags: java, http, servlets, jakarta-ee, basic-authentication

Suppose browser sent url:

```
http://user1:password1@myhost.com/index.html
```

Can this URL be sent with different username / password pair in http `Authorization` header?

For example:

```
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://user1:password1@myhost.com/index.html',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username2:password2')
            }
        })
```

If yes, then how to distinguish these places with [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)?

Which one is returned by [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser())?

And how to obtain another one?

**UPDATE**

As according to my Fiddler observations, web client does not keep username and password in URL even if it was passed explicitly. Instead, it put username and password into `Authorization` header. What happens if different values passed differently via javascript, I don't know. Anyway, only one username:password paid is sent.

But later behavior on error codes differs. If password was passed in URL, browser does not show authorization dialog on 401 error. Probably this is browser dependent.

Answer (score 1):

From header:

```
String header = request.getHeader("Authorization")
```

then decode it.

From URL:

```
URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL()); //http://username:password@hostname.com
String userInfo = url.getUserInfo() // username:password
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getUserInfo()

username/password should be passed in headers, not part of the URL. It seems browsers can skip it than in URL.

Answer (score 0):

The username and password within the url is not send to the server. It is just a convinience function of the browser to enter them, the browser will put/copy them into the `Authentication` header.